# How to know when file.write() has finished

Tags: python

I have a python server which receive image continuosly from a client.
For each image, I need to save it to disk and create a csv with the image path and a integer value for each of them.
My problem is that while the image is saving to disk, I reset the array of bytes..so only the top part of the image is visible, because I clear the array while the pc is still saving the image.
how do i know when the file has been saved completely?

```
conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connect with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
data = b''
while True:
    buf = conn.recv(4096)
    data = data + buf
    if len(buf) < 4096:
        date_string = str(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()).replace('.', '')
        with open('./images/' + date_string + '.jpg', 'ab') as f:
        f.write(data)
    data = b''
    conn.send(str.encode("OK\n"))
```

UPDATE:

I try to explain better the situation:

From an android device (client) I capture continuos frame from the camera, that I need to post-process for machine learning.
Each frame the device captures, will be send to the python server(code above). Before the client(the smartphone) sends the next frame, I have to make sure that the previous one was saved to the disk (the computer hdd). In fact, the line "conn.send(str.encode("OK\n")) need to say to the client "Ok, I saved the image, you can send me the next one". But before to clean the data variable, that contains the actual image, I have to make sure that f.write() has finished.

Comment: Your problem is not "how do I know when `file.write()` has finished" but "how do I know when the client socket has sent me all of the image data".

Comment: No, because I check if the buf is less than 4096. If the condition is true, then it means that it was the last piece of image. In fact, if I wait a few seconds in debug at line f.write(data), all the image is correctly saved. So, he need time before clean the data variable.

Comment: Try calling ```f.close()``` after ```f.write(data)```.

Comment: @KevinMüller still same problem...

Comment: Shouldnt you move the ```data = b''``` into the if part? Since then you only reset the data if you received the last image data? Since when you wait in debugger at the write line he wont get to the part where it resets the data, instead it just keeps appending to your data variable

Comment: @KevinMüller yes, but before reset the image, I need to write it to disk (the "data" variable contains all the byte of the image. I already tried to move the data = b'' inside the if statement, but the result is the same. Maybe it write the file in another thread, so when he goes to the next line and data is cleaned, it continue to write the image but without any byte data. Some image infact are corrupted. I need a sort of callback to know when it has finish to write the file...

Comment: Your assignment to `data` is **completely irrelevant**—it’s not even an in-place mutation, and it wouldn’t matter (on a single thread, at least) even then since `write` copies the data somewhere before returning.

Comment: I'd say the problem is that you're not telling the whole story. Please extract and provide a [mcve]. That should clear things up. Also, read [ask], as there are a few things amiss in your question.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yeah, your right..I updated my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) it seems like you should not check for the size of your data, instead you should just append until you are not receiving data anymore:

```
conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connect with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
data = b''
while True:
    buf = conn.recv(4096)
    if buf:
        data = data + buf
        conn.send(str.encode("OK\n"))
    else:
        break

date_string = str(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()).replace('.', '')
with open('./images/' + date_string + '.jpg', 'ab') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Maybe there is some packages inbetween that are not the same size but are not meant to be the last package.
Also this has further advantages since you never need to reset your data variable.

Comment: Also then you should be able to use the mode 'w' or 'wb' instead of 'ab' at ```with open()```

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question if you want to check it out!

Comment: Yes, with your "if buf:" instead of "if len(buf) < 4096:" now it works! Thank you so much!!